# Puts data in gridPanel dynamically?

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I would like , how to puts data in grid Panel when i clik on a tree's node ?

When , i clik on a node, it fires a itemclick events, i have model on parameters ...
now, i want to "write" the data's model on my gridPanel. I want to had one line on my grid !
With a grid Panel, i must to use store , so i have tested with memory store who contains an empty data properties .. ! I thought , i can putting data on the fly in my grid ... maybe i can't !

I need helps, thanks a lot :) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add data to a grid, you need to add the data to the grid's Store. There is a ton of documentation about adding new items, but you would do something like this:

```
var Item = grid.getStore().recordType;
var newItem = new Banner(
{
    // attributes of your newItem here
    // these would be the same as your Store
});

store.insert(0, newItem);
```

That would insert your new item as the first item in your store, and should automatically fire the grid to refresh. If it doesn't, you can manually fire a refresh by doing:

```
bannerGrid.getView().refresh();
```

[**Documentation for Store**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store). Take a look at the `add()` and `insert()` methods.

Comment: Yes :) ! Without on extjs 4 i haven't got recordType method !
but when i click on the node i have a model, i need just to using insert method with the model parameters ! :)

Thanks a lot for your well answer :)